# Converting a structure to an intptr

Tags: c#, class, marshalling, intptr

I have a class definition as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class OUR_MEM_STR
            {
                public byte[] p;
                public int  len;
            };
```

This is an equivalent defintion of the C structure below:

```
typedef struct
{
    void *p;
    int  len;
} OUR_MEM_STR;
```

I used byte[] instead of IntPtr type for member p becuase of the way it was being used thorughout c# project.

I have defined an object obj with len = 10 and p = new byte[10]

I want to make it an intptr. How do I get the size of the object for that?

```
 IntPtr pObj = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(obj.len + sizeof(int));
 Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, pObj, true);
```

See what I did there. It seems too hard coded. If I do the below snippet;

```
IntPtr pObj = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(obj));
```

Doing this  returns the wrong size because obj.p returns a size of 4 and not 10. Because of the memory taken by the pointer pointing to the byte array is 4 bytes.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you show us the C definition of the struct you are trying to replicate?

Comment: So, if I do IntPtr pObj = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(obj)); and use false parameter, it should be fine?

Comment: Thats so cool, it did. The intellisense hint while I was writing the structure to ptr function told me to use true. They confuse new devs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value is correct, `p` is a *pointer*, it takes 4 bytes.

You cannot leave it this way, there are *two* memory allocations.  The marshaller allocated the memory for the array.  It created a SAFEARRAY, a COM array type.  Pretty unlikely that your C code is going to be happy with that.  Declare it like this instead:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class OUR_MEM_STR {
    public IntPtr p;
    public int len;
};
```

And use Marshal.AllocHGlobal(10) to assign `p`.  Don't forget to clean-up again.

Don't pass *true* to StructureToPtr(), the memory allocated by AllocHGlobal() isn't initialized.  That's going to randomly crash your program.  You must pass *false*.

Comment: Thanks! Doesnt C# garbage collection clean up automatically?

Comment: No, you allocated unmanaged memory.  Calling Marshal.FreeHGlobal() twice is a hard requirement.  Beware that this must happen *after* your pinvoked code stopped using the struct.

Comment: Correct. Lil by lil I'm mastering pinvoke. Thanks to ppl like u on SO

Comment: Once, just before I come out of the function where the object was created, and the other time?

Comment: Once for the array, again for the struct.  Both have to be released.